# The logarithm product rule?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Proof of the logarithmic product rule:

> $y(x) = \ln (ax)$
>
> $y'(x) = 1/x$
>
> $\implies \ln (ax) = \ln(x) + c$
>
> Evaluating at $x=1$, we get $\ln(a) = \ln (1) + c \implies c = \ln a \implies \ln(ax) = \ln a + \ln x$.

My prof gave us the proof above. I don't understand why this proof is valid for all $x$ though. The proof entails setting $x$ to $1$, so why isn't this proof just valid if $x = 1$?

Please do not give me a proof of the product rule. I am specifically asking about the proof above.

Comment: I don't get it: what **exactly** are you asking, anyway??

Comment: why isn't this proof just valid if x=1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that somehow you know already that $y(x)=\ln (ax) \implies y'(x)=1/x$, which is not shown in your question.  Now you integrate the second equation with respect to $x$ and get $y(x)=\ln (x)+c$  You have two expressions for $y(x)$ so you can set them equal, giving $\ln (ax)=\ln(x)+c$  This has to be true for all $x$.  You can evaluate it for any $x$ and it still has to be true.  $x=1$ is a convenient point, as you can see because the rest of the demonstration works.  If $x=3$ were a convenient point you could evaluate it there, too

Answer (score 3):

Setting x equal to 1 was merely a sub-step whose purpose was to deduce the value of the constant c.  c is a "constant" in the sense that it doesn't depend on x, so even though we compute it using a fixed value for x, that value holds no matter what x is.  Now drop the assumption that x=1, go back to the GENERAL statement that ln(ax) = ln(x) + c, and plug in the value c=ln(a) (which was proven in the x=1 case, but again, is independent of x), and you get the desired result :).

Answer (score 3):

The equation $\ln(ax) = \ln(x) + c$ holds for every $x$. The purpose of evaluating at $x=1$ is to figure out the exact value of the arbitrary constant of integration. Thus, $c=\ln(a)$ and $\ln(ax) = \ln(x) + c$ implies that $\ln(ax) = \ln(x) + \ln(a)$ for any positive numbers $a$ and $x.$ This is the product rule for logarithms.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you understand this formulation better: if $a>0$ consider the function
$$
F(x)=\ln(ax)-\ln(a)-\ln(x) \qquad F:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$
Then you have
$$
F(1)=0
$$
and
$$
F'(x)=\dfrac{1}{ax} a - 0 - \dfrac{1}{x}=0
$$
You see that $F'=0$ on an interval, so $F$ must be constant $=F(1)$